# Can't push new local branch to remote repo

Tags: git

I always create a new feature branch (`git checkout -b feature-branch`) that I push (after doing `git add .` and `git commit "..."`) to remote repo by doing this:

`git push origin feature-branch`

Inexplicably, the same process failed today with the following error:

```
error: src refspec feature/feature-branch does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/myproject/myproject.git'
```

(note the sentence of the first line isn't even complete)

Why is this happening and how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: You said you wrote `git push origin feature-branch`, but the error message says you wrote `git push origin feature/feature-branch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are not pushing to the right branch or is there a typo error and this could be a probelm since your local branch and target branch should be same.. check out your current working branch name with this command `git show-branch`.

If that doesn't work try

`git init`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Your first commit message"`